Is Book of Genesis 3:14 to 3:19 supposed to be an example of Doomerism/Nihilism/Incelism?

“I will make your pains in childbearing very severe;
with painful labor you will give birth to children.
Your desire will be for your husband,
and he will rule over you.”

Now most women are going to see relationships as transactional, trying to seek the most competent male.
"He will rule over you" will make women more picky. It should inspire fear in the once equal with Adam, Eve? Who wants to be ruled by the poor, stupid, bad character male or the mediocre?

“Cursed is the ground because of you;
through painful toil you will eat food from it
all the days of your life.
18 It will produce thorns and thistles for you,
and you will eat the plants of the field.
19 By the sweat of your brow
you will eat your food
until you return to the ground,
since from it you were taken;
for dust you are
and to dust you will return.”

Now, most men have to work hard to support a woman and themselves who thinks the relationship is a shortchanged/bad one.
If I'm not seeing this correctly, why not?

The consequences of sin are bad. This should not be surprising. I don't see this relating directly to nihilism or incelism, however, nor would I describe Christianity as "doomeristic", although certainly we do recognize that the present world is ultimately fated to be destroyed (by fire).

If you're looking for only two broad brush stroke takeaways from this passage of Genesis I would suggest the following:

The entrance of the disposition of sin into the human nature has had detrimental effect on even the most fundamental of human relationships.

Everything that God created and ordained for the purpose of blessing and sustaining the humanity that he created has now been rendered painful and difficult because of our rebellion and in order to make us turn back to Him.


There's always a lot more to pull out of any particular passage but these are two foundational points upon which to build a deeper understanding.

From Is Genesis 3:16 about Pain in Childbirth? Yes? or No?:
‘itsabon is used only three times in the Bible. In each case it talks about what fieldwork will be like as a result of the curse on the ground.
God told the man the ground would be cursed because of him and he would experience ‘itsabon. In Genesis 5:29 the curse on the ground is again the subject of discussion.
The parents of Noah hoped he would relieve them of their ‘itsabon as each of them worked the cursed ground with their hands. This is about a dirt-under-your-fingernails experience. It is not about birth pangs.
Would the first woman as well as the man also experience ‘itsabon when outside of Eden? Would she would work the ground with her hands? Of course.
NIV incorrectly translates the opening words to the woman in Genesis 3:16 as follows: “I will make your pains in childbearing very severe” when the Hebrew words are not talking about pain in childbearing at all.
“Pain” is not the right word to use to translate ‘itsabon. It is more properly be translated as “toil,” or even better as “sorrowful toil” and it has to do with doing fieldwork of the cursed ground. Here is a better translation of Line 1 of Genesis 3:16:
I will greatly multiply your sorrowful toil and your conception.

What does "conception" mean in "I will greatly multiply your sorrowful toil and your conception?"

It means that God will increase the amount of children that Eve is going to have. Before the Fall, Adam and Eve did not have any children.
